# Form Field flexible shadow with CSS

Tags: html, css, forms, xhtml, shadow

I have a form to be worked upon. Here is the image

[image: Form Field Shadow]

The problem is every form field has a shadow on left, right and bottom which should be flexible. I have not started my work on it at all but not able to think of best solution for this design with CSS2 not CSS3 [Requirement :( ] . Can anyone help me out or suggest me any solution??

Answer (score 1):

Use the following cross browser shawdow properties.

```
input{
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #ccc;
    /* For IE 8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#cccccc')";
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#cccccc');
}
```

change the values as needed

Comment: box-shadow is a css3 property...The question says she needs a css2 solution !

Comment: The last two lines are not css2 either...its a microsoft IE filter !

Comment: Yes, The combination will make a cross browser compatible shadow. OP's css3 avoidance is clearly a cross browser issue. This fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

since u insist on css2...

You will have to use  images positioned relative to the input controls...